# Best way to differentiate between browser requests and requests from mobile apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, httpwebrequest

I have some actions in my app that require a user to have logged in on the website, and some that require a "person" (a mobile app user basically) to have authenticated.  In order to know whether i need to push the current request through the mobile authentication, i'd like to be able to tell whether the request came from a browser or from an iphone for example.

Is there a request header or something i can look at for this?

thanks, max

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [mobile_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu)

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks @cbrulak.  However, the format of the requests from the mobile app in question is xml, so i don't want it switched to :mobile.  I'll definitely remember that for the future though.  I ended up doing this:  `if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /MobileAppName|libcurl/`.  (libcurl is just there so i can simulate the mobile app from curl)