# Distinguish between http mobile browser and mobile app request

Tags: android, ios, http, user-agent, captivenetwork

I read some post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360926/best-way-to-differentiate-between-browser-requests-and-requests-from-mobile-apps), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537950/how-to-distinguish-between-mobile-app-and-browser) and some other without response. However seems I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305867/distinguish-between-iphone-web-browser-and-iphone-app-user-agent) the solution for IOS device.

I need to reject any http request from any app of any device and process only request from web browser, so the mainly question is:

There is a definitive way to tell if an HTTP request is made from a mobile app or from a web browser?

Thanks

*Example: I receive all http request start from mobile/tablet (I'm developing application behind wifi hotspot), so i process request from Facebook App, Whatsup App and browser. I have to reject request from Facebook and Whatsup and process only request from browser. Apps User-agent seems the same of native device browser.*

Comment: No there is no definitive way as apps can fake any value for a user agent.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one thing. Set custom user-agent from application side.

You can set custom user-agent in both android and iphone during web-service call request.

**For Android**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
```

**For Iphone**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] 
                                       initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[yourURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSString *userAgent = "iphone";
[urlRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Check in request header if user-agent is "android" or "iphone" is from application and other-wise from browser.

Comment: Thanks Biraj, but i need to differentiate all app (like facebook app, whatsup etc.) request from browser request.

Answer (score 1):

you can check for the user-agent in the request header,
I remember mobile browsers send a different value for user-agent and desktop browsers a different one.
Just debug user-agent header and validate based on the values.

Comment: Thanks Eric, App's User-Agent seems the same of native browser device.